# SSRS Trying to pass parameters within URL, not working

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to create an URL to another paginated report. Eventually I want the URL to pass two parameters that are given in the initial report, but because I'm new to this I'm first trying to give a fixed value.

At first I kept getting the default value in the parameter `Periode`, but now I'm at the point that the parameter is set to `select a value` but I can't seem to get the value I'm giving in the URL:

```
myreportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/ReportName&Periode=Januari+2017
```

Picture of the screen i get with the URL above:
[image]

Parameter values available:

[image: Values]

[image]

Here are some of the URL's I tried:

```
myreportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/ReportName&rs:Command=Render&Periode.Period.period=Februari+2017

myreportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/ReportName&rs:Command=Render&Periode.Period.period=%5BPeriode%5D.%5BPeriod%5D.%5BPeriod%5D.%26%255%B2017%5D.%5B2%5D

myreportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/ReportName?:embed=y&:display_count=no&:linktarget=_self&:tabs=no&:showVizHome=no&SelectionList.SelectedItem=%5BPeriode%5D.%5BPeriod%5D.%5BPeriod%5D.%26%5%B2017%5D.%5B2%5D

myreportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/ReportName&:embed=y&:display_count=no&:linktarget=_self&:tabs=no&:showVizHome=no&%5BPeriode%5D.%5BKey%5D.%5BKey%5D=%5BPeriode%5D.%5BPeriod%5D.%5BPeriod%5D.%26%255%B2017%5D.%5B2%5D

myreportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/ReportName&Periode=%5BPeriode%5D.%5BPeriod%5D.%5BPeriod%5D.%26%255%B2017%5D.%5B2%5D
```

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots of your report design and what happens when you try to load that URL?

Comment: here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU2d4.jpg

Comment: What values are available to select in the `Periode` drop down?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PHBm.jpg ( 'Januari 2017', 'Februari 2017' etc)

Comment: could you please provide code/steps how you adjust periode parameters with report ?

Comment: I added some of the url's i tried in the post

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your URL to the following:

```
myreportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/ReportName&rs:Command=Render&Periode=Januari+2017
```

Remember that your parameter name in the URL must match your parameter name in the report and not the prompt that the user sees and that the value passed must match one of the available values, not the labels that are shown to the user.

Comment: As far as I can see, the values are the same as the labels shown. And I tried to adjust the parameters in I think all possible ways but then I get an error and see nothing at all https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKM7X.png

Comment: @avk  You have not included the `&rs:Command=Render` part of the URL in my answer.

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't make a difference, still get the same -select value-

Comment: You'll need to show the parameter properties and the list of values that populate it. I agree with iamdave, I think you may not be passing the parameter values, I think you are passing the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same thing, I found out it's because I had a non-supported datatype set for the parameter from the SQL original report index value, ex. I used the index to point to a value but I had the data type set as a float which is not supported so what I did is I divided the index value on 100, so I guess if you change the data type and check it might work